# What Windows groups/users are localized in non-English environments?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to write a PowerShell script which assigns some permissions to specific users/groups, but I want to write it to work with any language system I encounter. In order to do this I want to understand which groups/users have different names in Windows and which are constant.

I have been able to find an article which says that the `BUILTIN\Administrator` user is different, but I can't find anything about `BUILTIN\Administrators` or `DOMAIN\Domain Admins` groups, or `CREATOR OWNER`, `SYSTEM`, `NETWORK SERVICE`

I'm doing some testing on a few machines and languages myself, but I would prefer documentation which I can rely on even for the languages/Windows versions I don't have access to, and it seems like it should be out there somewhere. Sorry if this question is obvious or silly, I am pretty new to using Windows accounts in general, and have no experience with non-English systems.

Comment: Assume that _all built-ins may have localized names_, never rely on names :-)

Comment: Heres a start https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13813.localized-names-for-administrator-account-in-windows.aspx

Comment: Yeah Daniel, that was the only one I was able to find. I guess I'll just have to use SID's to find the account names and then call functions from them. Was hoping MS would've made another note somewhere :/